# How to set month name in x-axis for plotting timestamp data in python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

I have extracted a data frame from a csv file which has timestamp data. The index is set to the timestamp column. Now while plotting some reading for a particular period of days I get the timestamp on the x-axis. Instead of this I prefer to plot **date-(month name)-year midnight/morning/afternoon/evening**

So for example. the data is "2010-03-30 00:14" and I would like to print on the axis as "30-March-2010 Midnight". This is my code,

```
f0 = plt.figure(figsize=(20,20))
gs = gridspec.GridSpec(5, 5)
ax0 = f0.add_subplot(gs[0,:])
df.loc['2010-03-30 00:14':'2010-04-02 23:59', 'S1'].plot()
ax0.set_ylabel('Sensor1')

ax1 = f0.add_subplot(gs[1, :])
df.loc['2010-03-30 00:14':'2010-04-02 23:59', 'S2'].plot()
ax1.set_ylabel('Sensor2')

ax2 = f0.add_subplot(gs[2,:])
df.loc['2010-03-30 00:14':'2010-04-02 23:59', 'S3'].plot()
ax2.set_ylabel('Sensor3')

ax3 = f0.add_subplot(gs[3, :])
df.loc['2010-03-30 00:14':'2010-04-02 23:59', 'S4'].plot()
ax3.set_ylabel('Sensor4')

ax4 = f0.add_subplot(gs[4, :])
df.loc['2010-03-30 00:14':'2010-04-02 23:59', 'E2'].plot()
ax4.set_ylabel('Power')
```

[image]

I tried to follow the description from https://scentellegher.github.io/programming/2017/05/24/pandas-bar-plot-with-formatted-dates.html but didn't help me much. Please provide your valuable suggestions. Thank you!